# Free vpn client for mac

Tags: vpn, mac, pptp

I need an free vpn client for mac os x leopard that supports PPTP

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OS X has a built in PPTP client.
http://www.bol.ucla.edu/services/vpn/pptp/docs/macosx.html#leopardpp

Comment: +1 No need to add another when the built-in one does the job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Shimo](http://www.shimoapp.com/), which is really simplifies the VPN management process. Macworld did a pretty good write up on the application in Aug of '07, but much of the article is still relevent: http://www.macworld.com/article/59355/2007/08/shimo.html  It does nag you asking you to license it, but the application is fully featured even if you don't license it and you can easily minimize the nag window.

Comment: Thank you, but built in solved my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not Free, but only $9 - Viscosity VPN [www.viscosityvpn.com](http://www.viscosityvpn.com)
Supports only 10.5 or later.

Answer (score -1):

There is an interesting alternative to the builtin: [JollyFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html)

Comment: OP was asking about a VPN client, not a VNC client :)